# Git: No permission to access folder after merging

Tags: git, github, git-pull

I locally checked out a new branch `feat` based of `dev` on my Windows machine. I then did some commits and pushed the `feat` branch to my online repo at GitHub. These commits included the creation of a new sub-folder. I then created a pull request at GitHub in order to merge `feat` back into `dev`. Everything went fine.

Now, back at my local machine, I checked out my `dev` branch and performed a `git pull`. This is where my problem started. Git tells me that I don't have the permission to access the newly created sub-folder. As a result, I'm not able to pull my `dev` branch to my local machine.
Using `ls -la` within git bash, it shows no differences to other sub-folders (drwxr-xr-x; I am the owner).

Here's the exact error msg from within git bash:

`error: cannot stat 'sub-folder': Permission denied`

Also, I can't checkout my local `feat` branch anymore. It gives me the same error message.

So, what's the way tho go from here? Should I have done something differently in order to prevent me from facing this issue?

Comment: what operating system and file system are you using?

Comment: I am using a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Once I closed down MATLAB, I could access the blocked sub-folder. `git pull` worked fine. Everything is clean, now.